# How to make a string safe to be used in gsub?

Tags: ruby, gsub

This is the code:

```
pattern = /(a)(.*?)(z)/
 => /(a)(.*?)(z)/ 

# Correct
str = "my // string"
 => "my // string" 
"agggz".gsub(pattern, '\1' + str + '\3')
 => "amy // stringz" 

# Wrong - there is one missing slash
str = "my \\\\ string"
 => "my \\\\ string" 
"agggz".gsub(pattern, '\1' + str + '\3')
 => "amy \\ stringz"
```

When I have a pattern described in a string, I could use `Regexp.escape` to make sure that the pattern will work as I expected.

What I'm looking for is something similar, but for the second parameter of `gsub`, that is, independently of the `str`, when used as the value to be replaced in the `gsub`, it will copy correctly the value to the position.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try it with a block instead.

Comment: Show example code that includes the substitution strings. You are supposed to show code that duplicates the problem. Your description helps but there are multiple ways we can define strings that mask the problem so we need to see what you are doing.

Comment: @theTinMan rewrote the question. Please see if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with:

```
pattern = /(a)(.*?)(z)/                   # => /(a)(.*?)(z)/
str = "my \\\\ string"                    # => "my \\\\ string"
```

Instead of doing:

```
"agggz".gsub(pattern, '\1' + str + '\3')  # => "amy \\ stringz"
```

I'd do it like this:

```
"agggz"[pattern] # => "agggz"
$1 + str + $3 # => "amy \\\\ stringz"
```

Most of the time we really want to match a string to extract stuff out, and occasionally we want to munge a string to convert it into something else. In this case you want to extract stuff, so do that; Take the retrieved values and make what you really want by concatenation.

But there's a lot that doesn't make sense about the question and examples. If you know the string starts with `a`, and ends with `z`, then don't bother with a regex or `gsub` (or `sub`) at all:

```
'a' + str + 'z' # => "amy \\\\ stringz"
```

If you don't know what the first and last letters are, then why do you search for `(a)` or `(z)`? Your pattern should use wildcards: `/^(.).*?(.)$/`:

```
pattern = /^(.).*(.)$/
"agggz"[pattern]

$1 + str + $2  # => "amy \\\\ stringz"
```

But, why even use a pattern or a method like `sub` or `gsub`?

```
target = "agggz"
target[0] + str + target[-1] # => "amy \\\\ stringz"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it doesn't really answers the question but it shows what I should do to get it right. The pattern is simplified to not add unecessary details in the question, the correct pattern in my code is `/(\s*".*?"\s*=\s*")(.*?)(";)/m`, which doesn't really matter in the question.

Comment: Regex baffle people because they make them too complicated. Start with simple ones and carefully add complexity. You don't want what's in `(.*?)` so don't capture it. Any time you have something like `(";)`, I recommend you don't bother capturing it either. You know what's supposed to be there so append it using a literal string.

Comment: That is a good comment, but I use this regexp many times over the code, so in some places, I have to capture the middle group. The last part is wrong, it should be `("\s*;)`, otherwise I could do as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Even if the last capture could have trailing white-space, it can't be significant, otherwise there wouldn't be `\s*`, meaning "none or some". Again, at that point, you should be able to ignore it and append `';'`. It's your choice, but, from a lot of years spent working with data, and based on your patterns, it seems like you're making it too hard.